# How to improve the performance of a Gridview that contains 10000 data records in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I had an interview Question .

Q. how to improve performance of a `Gridview contains 100000 Records` of data(Datasource might be XML or DB) in c# asp.net ?

I was just blinking as i had no answer for this .Please Give me the solution for this. If possible please give one demo.

Comment: Post how you are doing it now.  For all we know, you already have the best possible implementation.

Comment: My immediate response is to implement paging. Only render what the user can see. (And no-one needs to see 100000 records on screen at once!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No gridview should contain 100000 records.

Your data source may contain 10 times that number of records, it doesn't matter. If you present a user more than 100 records on screen, it would be difficult to work with that data.

Select a datasource that supports paging for the gridview, that way you are only working with the number of records to be displayed on screen.

For a database you can use something like [SqlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). 
The default [XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx) does not support paging, in such cases the grid will have all records in memory and handle paging itself. For xml with large number of records consider using an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx), where you can implement paging yourself.

If you have a choice, always select a data source that supports paging.

Comment: By Default ObjectDataSource/ SqlDataSource/XmlDataSource or all datasources stores data in Dataset . M i right ? But As per Experts says, storing data in dataset will decrease the performance of the WebPage. Here

Comment: No, data sources do not store their data in DataSets by default. Sources like SqlDataSource can return the data as DataSet(All records in memory) or DataReader(Access one row at a time). DataSets will only cause drastic performance drops if your try to load large amounts of data. If you are paging your data, the overhead of a DataSet too would be very small

Comment: Boss, everything fine. But as per question what should you do to improve the performance ? What should i implement there. DefinitelyNo to dataset as it decreses performance. as interviewer told. So, What should i do ?

Comment: Paginate it. Simple. That is the answer. What I did was explain to you, how to do it. If after one year, you are still looking for the answer, you have definitely not tried solving it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To fix such a GridView, I think a good approach would be to:

- Add paging (as others have already pointed out)
- Add filtering/searching
- Add a cap/limit for maximum number of rows shown

The filtering + max limit for results is (in my opinion) a good way to keep the size of the grid manageable. If the max limit is hit using some specified set of filters (=search terms) you could show a message about it to the user and encourage him/her to specify a more specific search if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, a gridview should not hold so many rows.
In your interview, they wanted to see if you can say that its bad implemented rather then to check your programming skill.

But if one insist for good performance, I would suggest to use Repeater instead of Gridview.

Cheers,
Ran